# Automatic generation of HAML from HTML in SublimeText 2?

Tags: haml, sublimetext2, toolchain

I would like to have SublimeText show the HTML result of parsing my HAML in another window, live, as I type the HAML.

Does anyone have an idea of how to make this happen? In, e.g., WebStorm there are file watchers that do this, but is there something like that built into ST2?

Comment: Apparently the answer is to go back to vim: https://github.com/michalliu/haml-instant

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar to this with Typescript, only I only updated the Javascript output when I saved the file. First, I would say to take a look at [SublimeBuildOnSave](https://github.com/a-sk/sublime-build-on-save/blob/master/autobuild.py). That'll show you how to hook into the save function and see what file is being saved.

When you've got the general idea, you can take a look [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html#sublime.View) and mess around with opening another pane (or using the existing pane) to show the compiled output.

It's pretty simple to make a simple version of this. If you want more advanced features like live compiling, it'll take a bit more effort, but it's not impossible. But the above scenario worked just fine for Typescript for me. (If I find where I left that code, I'll post it.)